# convert API query from Python to MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab, rest, post

I thought it should be straightforward but I struggled to convert the following API query from python to MATLAB

```
import json
import requests
url='http://amp.pharm.mssm.edu/Enrichr/addList'
gstr='\n'.join([
'PHF14','RBM3','MSL1','PHF21A','ARL10'])
payload={'list':(None, gstr)}
response=requests.post(url, files=payload)
```

here is what I tried on Matlab

```
gstr = 'PHF14\nRBM3\nMSL1\nPHF21A\nARL10'
input = struct('list', gstr);
response = webwrite(url, input)
```

EDIT:
I get the following error on MATLAB

```
The server returned the message: "Bad Request" for URL (with HTTP response code 400)
```

I am on Matlab R2015b.

Comment: What is the actual issue you're having?

Comment: You might want to look at [webread](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/webread.html) (R2014b and above)?

Comment: none of the native functions, webread, webwrite and urlread support uploading files to a webservice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MATLAB doesn´t natively support writing files to a webservice.
I used this [MathWorks](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27189-urlreadpost-url-post-method-with-binary-file-uploading) function to do so, which solved the problem.